# Emoji for jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, emoji

I've built a site on Github pages with Jekyll. Recently I tried running an emoji_for_jekyll plugin. When I build and run the site locally, it seems to work. However, when I commit and view it online the emoji disappear and all that's left is the syntax (:smile:)

Here is a page on my site [http://joshuahouston.github.io/code/2014/12/10/the-emoji-test.html](https://joshuahouston.github.io/code/2014/12/10/the-emoji-test.html)

This is the resource I've followed. The 3 steps seem easy enough.

```
Install the emoji_for_jekyll gem:

gem install emoji_for_jekyll
Add emoji_for_jekyll to the list of gems in config.yml:

gems: ["emoji_for_jekyll"]
See beautiful emoji!
or

Copy emoji_for_jekll.rb and emoji.json into the _plugins directory
```

And you can view my site's pages on Github and they're even working there! https://github.com/joshuahouston/joshuahouston.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-12-10-the-emoji-test.markdown

Do you know what I'm missing? Why aren't the pages being generated correctly for the site but correctly elsewhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not all plugins can be run on Gitub pages ([see documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/)).

If you want to use emojies on your gh-pages, you'll have to use [parkr jemoji](https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji).

- `gem install jemoji`
- remove your `_plugins` folder content
- change gems in `_config.yml` to `gems: ["jemoji"]`
- test with a `jekyll serve`
- push to Github
- be happy ;-)

Comment: For more information, you need to add `gem jemoji` to **Gemfile** and run `bundle install`. Don't forget to add to **_config.yml**. [Jemoji's repo](https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji) on Github.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I test directly on Github. I did two changes:

Step 1: add `gem 'jemoji'` to Gemfile

[image]

Step 2: add `- jemoji` to _config.yml

[image]

Comment: If you came here to make sure the GitHub Pages build pipeline works properly, these are actually the current steps that are needed to make the emojis work.

Comment: I know this answer was written with _probably_ more current context, but it could use a link to the repository for Jemoji.